# apt alternative for proxy environment with bash shell

Tags: beginner, bash, linux, shell

As I am new to bash scripting, and want to use apt-get in my university.  I know that many people have issues when trying to do so.  My focus is simplicity and ease of use, but still need to be somewhat robust.

```
#!/bin/bash 
string="install"
errormsg="\n\tInvalid input\n You should run this script with the following structure:\n\n sudo apt-proxy-install.sh install USERNAME PASSWORD\n\n "
DIRECTORY=~/bin/
if [ "$1" = "$string" ] && { ! ([ -z "$3" ] || [ -z "$3" ]) }
   then 
         if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
            mkdir ~/bin/
         fi
         printf "#!/bin/bash\nhttp_proxy=""http://$2:$3@10.20.10.50:3128"" sudo apt-get \${@:2}" > ~/bin/apt-proxy
         chmod 777 ~/bin/apt-proxy
         PATH=~/bin:$PATH
         addpath="export $PATH"
         sudo cat ~/.bashrc $addpath > ~/.bashrc
   else
         printf "$errormsg"
fi
```

My question is: is this code acceptable, or should I improve it? If the answer is not, then please give me some hints.

Comment: Assuming that apt-get should always use the HTTP proxy, configure [`/etc/apt/apt.conf`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy) with `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@10.20.10.50:3128"`. You _might_ consider the risk of storing a plaintext password to be acceptable if `apt.conf` is readable only by root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing passwords in text files is never a good idea, **especially** if you give that file world-readable permissions.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

mkdir -p ~/bin/

# add ~/bin to PATH if not already there
echo '[[ :"$PATH": == *:"$HOME/bin":* ]] || PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"' >> .bashrc

# create the apt-proxy script
cat <<'END_SCRIPT' > ~/bin/apt-proxy
#!/bin/bash

stty -echo
printf "Password for %s: " "$LOGNAME"
read password
stty echo
echo

export http_proxy="http://${LOGNAME}:${password}@10.20.10.50:3128"
sudo -S apt-get "$@" <<< "$password"
END_SCRIPT

chmod 755 ~/bin/apt-proxy

cat <<INSTRUCTIONS
The apt-proxy script has been installed. 
You may need to log out and log back in before you can use it.

usage: apt-proxy package ...
INSTRUCTIONS
```

- `mkdir -p dir` will silently do nothing if the directory already exists
- you only need to add the user's `bin` dir to the PATH if it is not already there
- DO NOT store the user's password. Have the user enter it each time.
- you *should* not even need to use `sudo` to edit files in your home directory.
- 777 permissions is overly generous: the world does not have to be able to edit the file
- use `sudo -S` and pass the user's password via stdin

Comment: Additionally, you almost always want to quote `"$@"` to expand the command line arguments robustly.

Answer (score 1):

**NO!**

Storing plaintext passwords in a world-readable file is not acceptable.

Making an executable file world-writable is not acceptable.

Asking for a password to be entered as a command-line parameter, where it would likely end up in ~/.bash_history, is not acceptable.  The password would also be temporarily be visible to all users via `/bin/ps`, which is also bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

This line has readability problems:

```
if [ "$1" = "$string" ] && { ! ([ -z "$3" ] || [ -z "$3" ]) }
```

You put `$3` twice; I assume you meant `$2` for one of them.

Since `"$string"` is just `install`, you might as well say `install` instead.

The compound conditional is hard to understand.  Apply De Morgan's laws to obtain

```
if [ "$1" = install ] && ! [ -z "$2" ] && ! [ -z "$3" ]
```

… which is just

```
if [ "$1" = install ] && [ -n "$2" ] && [ -n "$3" ]
```

I would introduce explaining variables

```
command="$1"
username="$2"
password="$3"
if [ "$command" = install ] && [ -n "$username" ] && [ -n "$password" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This line…

```
sudo cat ~/.bashrc $addpath > ~/.bashrc
```

… is actually *extremely* problematic.

You will almost certainly **wipe out the existing contents of `~/.bashrc`**: the shell will likely truncate `~/.bashrc` before it runs `sudo`, and `sudo` runs `cat`, and `cat` reads the file.  See [Unix Big Redirection Mistake #1](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/12w/notes/270_redirection.txt).  The way to append to a file is using `echo "$blah" >> ~/.bashrc`.

The `$addpath` variable is incorrectly defined as `addpath="export $PATH"`.  You would be trying to export a variable named `~/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` because there is no `PATH=…` assignment.  You meant `addpath="export PATH=\"$PATH\""`.

Furthermore, `cat $addpath` has two errors: it's the wrong command (you want `echo`), and you failed to double-quote its argument.  Therefore, it will just try to read files named `export` and `PATH=~/bin:…` — if you're lucky.  If you're unlucky, `$PATH` could expand to a string that contains a nasty shell command.  That scenario is admittedly farfetched, but that kind of carelessness in quoting is how exploits get introduced.  **When writing shell scripts, double-quote *every* variable you use unless you have a good reason not to.**

`sudo` is unnecessary for that operation; it could even backfire if the `sudoers` doesn't allow `cat` to be executed.  By the way, `sudo` would only elevate the `cat ~/.bashrc` to root privileges; the writing would still be done using output redirection in the non-elevated context.

`~/.bashrc` is not a good place to put a statement to edit `$PATH`, since it gets executed with every interactive shell.  If you run `bash` from within Bash, the subshell would unexpectedly have its `$PATH` redefined.  A more appropriate place might be `~/.bash_profile`.

After correcting for the mistakes above, with the code

```
PATH="~/bin:$PATH"
addpath="export PATH=\"$PATH\""
echo "$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

… you would be "freezing" the current value of `$PATH` into `~/.bash_profile`.  Instead, you probably want to prepend `~/bin` to whatever `$PATH` exists when `~/.bash_profile` is executed in the future (notice the single quotes instead of double quotes):

```
echo 'export PATH=~/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```